# ¿Cómo extraigo el primer campo y último de una tabla en sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito obtener un resultado como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, heads únicos seguidos de dos columnas que son la primera fila y última de la columna Description correspondiente a cada head.

He probado con este código pero en algo me estoy equivocando porque me da un resultado que no es el que quiero. Básicamente lo que hago es relacionar una tabla de heads únicos con el top(1) de la tabla general ordenada asc y desc para obtener la última y la primera línea.

```
with cte(pos,head,item,description) as (
   select 
      row_number() over(order by head)pos,
        *
    from #tmp
   )
 select 
    cabecera,
    t.description,
    s.description
from 
    (select distinct head as cabecera from cte)r
left join (
    select top(1) head,Description from cte 
    order by pos asc
   )t on t.head=cabecera
     left join (
       select top(1) head,Description from cte order by pos desc
      )s on s.head=cabecera
```

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Añado esta solución que va bien con pocos registros, pero con muchos es prohibitiva. Son unas subconsultas con las que obtengo el resultado esperado, pero no es nada efectiva. A ver si con esto aclaro un poco más lo que quiero obtener:

```
with cte(pos,orden,error,motivo) as (
select 
    row_number() over(partition by orden order by (select null))pos,
    *
from #tmp
 )select 
    orden,
    (select top(1) motivo from cte where orden=t.orden)Error,
    (select top(1) motivo from cte where orden=t.orden order by pos 
     desc)Motivo
 from (select distinct orden from cte)t
```

Y este es el resultado que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu ejemplo no se entiende, por favor dale el formato correcto para entenderte

Comment: Te deseo suerte

Comment: Esta claro que el primer nivel de ordenamiento es `head` pero cual sería la columna a ordenar dentro de cada `head`?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho se ordena magicamente...

Comment: Lo importante, para ordenar en una db, la db tiene que saber ordenar.. y sabes que sabe ordenar una db?? por alfabeto, por numeros, por fechas (que en realidad, los 3, son todos numeros)... entonces.. por cual columna queres ordenar??? salvo que numeres item de alguna forma, entonces no se puede ordenar por esa...

Comment: Hola Patricio, te explico. La columna “head” contiene órdenes de proceso, la de “ítem” códigos de error y la de “description” el motivo del error. Cada orden que tenga un error sera completada con varias lineas, siendo la primera el código de error y la última el motivo de ese error. Las líneas intermedias, cuyo número puede variar, no me sirven. Por tanto quiero obtener el número de orden en una columna, en otra columna el código de error y en una tercera columna la descripción del mismo, tal cual se muestra en la 2da imagen.

Comment: Gbianchi, no entendí nada de lo que has escrito. Una db tiene que saber ordenar? Eso que quiere decir? Es ridículo.

Comment: En una BD relacional no existe el concepto de orden natural, el orden esta dado siempre por una clausula `ORDER BY`, un `select * from tabla` puede devolverte las filas como el motor se le ocurra, o al menos no te ofrece ninguna garantía que el orden sea siempr el mismo. Por eso mi pregunta, me da la impresión que faltan columnas en tu query.

Comment: @gbianchi `ORDER BY @Magic`

Comment: ¿Hay alguna columna tipo `FechaAlta` o similar?

Comment: si, tiene que saber ordenar... no hay concepto de primero y ultimo, SALVO, que pongas fechas, o numeros de id, o algo.. la DB no guarda en orden, guarda como se le ocurre, y luego muestra como se le ocurre (en realidad, como le resulte mas rapido).. entonces si, si vos queres ordenar por alguna columna magica, tenes que explciarle como ordenar por esa columna magica... para evitar todo esto, ponele fecha a las filas, y listo, ordena por fecha y quedate con la menor y la mayor...

Comment: Hola Patricio, ¿has revisado el código SQL que yo he incluido? En él se puede apreciar un campo generado con la función Row_Number que utilizo para ordenar las órdenes ascendente y descendentemente. El objetivo es extraer la primera y última fila de cada orden PVXXX. Creo que se aprecia perfectamente el resultado en la segunda imagen.

Comment: **Los comentarios han sido [movidos al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150529/discussion-on-question-by-jose-manuel-como-extraigo-el-primer-campo-y-ultimo-de); por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí.** Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los [propósitos de los comentarios](/help/privileges/comment). Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una [respuesta](/help/how-to-answer), en [meta], o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé por qué tratas de usar el órden cuando no estás ordenando por nada confiable (Usas una columna de valores iguales o un valor constante que es lo que retorna `SELECT NULL`).

En vez de eso, puedes usar un agregado condicional para convertir las filas en columnas.

```
SELECT head,
    MAX( CASE WHEN Item LIKE 'Error%' THEN Description END) AS Error,
    MAX( CASE WHEN Item = 'Descripción' THEN Description END) AS Motivo
FROM #tmp
GROUP BY head;
```

Eso será una solución más sencilla y mucho más eficiente.

Comment: Sin duda es la solución ideal Luis, breve, concisa y eficaz. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Adjunto esta propuesta. Creo que será eficiente también con grupos grandes.
Simplificaría bastante si tuvieras (como he dicho en los comentarios) un campo `ID` (por ejemplo autoincremental y PK) o un campo `DATETIME` (o similar).

Además te evitaría el uso del `ROW_NUMBER...` que para mi es bastante engorroso.

```
Select T3.head, b1.item, b2.Description from 
    (SELECT row_number() over(order by head) pos,item  from cte) as T1

INNER JOIN
(select distinct t2.head head,MIN(t2.pos) lo, max(t2.pos) hi from 
  (SELECT row_number() over(order by head) pos,c.* from cte C) as T2
 Group by (t2.head) ) AS T3 on (t1.pos=T3.lo)

INNER JOIN (SELECT row_number() over(order by head) pos,*  from cte) as B1 ON (t3.lo=B1.pos)
INNER JOIN (SELECT row_number() over(order by head) pos,*  from cte) as B2 ON (t3.hi=B2.pos)
```

Esta SQL, con un grupo de datos como el tuyo, debería devolver algo como esto, que creo que es lo que necesitas; ***Además no utiliza tablas temporales***:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto Germán, esto ya tiene una pinta que se asemeja a lo que busco. Lo pruebo y te confirmo. Por cierto, la tabla temporal no es porque la necesite, fue algo que creé como prueba para publicarlo aquí y no atacar la tabla de producción. Gracias por tu ayuda.